# Connecting multiple constraints to a single outlet

Tags: xcode, constraints, iboutlet

I have a bunch of objects, all equally spaced from each other. The constraints are set correctly for 3.5" screen, but for the 4" screen I want them farther apart (i.e. the distance between each object still the same, but larger).

I currently change constraints programmatically like this:

```
self.usernameVerticalSpace.constant = 256;
```

But if e.g. 8 constraints will be kept exactly the same as each other, but all increased at once, it seems like there should be a way to do that to one outlet, instead of 8 individual outlets. Is there a way to link all these constraints to one outlet, so I only have to change one value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you heard about IBOutletCollection? When you link any object from IB to VC code, in popup window you can select IBOutletCollection Option.

Tell me if it is not useful or if more info needed

Comment: You sir, are beautiful. What I was looking for was a single pointer that affected multiple objects, but an array generated automagically is just as good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an IBOutletCollection like this in code

`@IBOutlet var constraintsCollection: [NSLayoutConstraint]!`

Then click inside the small circle infront of the line just added and drag to link each constraint you want to add to the constraintsCollection one after the other in IB.

[image]

Once you have added one by one all the constraints to the Constraint Collection, it will contain all constraints like shown below
[image]